# In Excel how do I find a column then sum between two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel I have a pivottable:

| Project | 11/1/2021 | 11/2/2021 | 11/3/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dept 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Dept 2 | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| Dept 3 | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| Dept 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 |

The table spans the full length of the month.  I need a calculation that would find the department I input then sums all figures between today's date and the last day of the month:

| Dept | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Dept 1 | 15 |

I have tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Today()<=B1:K1)*(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)>=B1:K1))*(A2:A5="Dept 1")*(B2:K5)
```

and various different vlookups but I can't figure out how to both find the correct row and then sum everything between the two dates in that row.

Comment: Here is my guess, since you are using a pivot table the "dates" are actually strings that look like dates.  Try: `=SUMPRODUCT((Today()<=--B1:K1)*(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)>=--B1:K1)*(A2:A5="Dept 1")*(B2:K5))`

Comment: Why don't you do the calculation on the base data of the pivot table? It might be easier - and the dates are dates - not headers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following structure:

[image: .]

Try this, it works:

```
SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($B$2,$A:$A,0),COLUMN($B$6))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH($B$2,$A:$A,0),MATCH($B$3,$6:$6,0)),TRUE))
```